# Find the value of x

Tags: fractions

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{4^2}\right)\ldots\left(1-\frac{1}{2011^2}\right)=\frac{x}{2\cdot 2012}$$

Help me solve this, obviously there is a shortcut to solve it, but I have tried a lot and I've come up with something confusing!

Comment: Did you try rewriting the factors along the lines of $1-1/n^2=(n^2-1)/n^2=(n-1)(n+1)/n^2$? It looks to me like you could get some cancellation going …

Comment: **Hint:** The product telescopes.

Comment: yea, I wrote this way, but actually it's not way of solving this

Comment: Something about the writing of this feels like a competition math problem.

Comment: When you cancel it, the answer should be $\frac{x+2}{2x+2}$ where x is the number of terms. So, in this case, x=2011, so the numerator is x+2=2013.

Comment: @Asimov I think this is (at least) from an Estonian math competition from 2010, with different numbers, maybe. Can't find a link, but I was in that competition.

Comment: @gtrrebel I would have guessed from 2011, or 2012. The numbers they use are never random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the hint (given by @Harald Hanche-Olsen) and write out some terms you will see a pattern emerging:$$\require{cancel}\frac{1.\cancel{3}}{2.\cancel{2}}\frac{\cancel{2}.\cancel{4}}{\cancel{3}.\cancel{3}}\frac{\cancel{3}.5}{\cancel{4}.4}...$$Can you see how all the intermediate terms will cancel out?

Comment: BTW: I tried using the latext \cancel{3} notation to show the terms that would cancel but it doesn't seem to work anymore - is this a new bug?

Comment: No, you have to put \require{cancel} after the first $.

Comment: Perhaps split it up as $\cfrac 12\cdot \cfrac 32\cdot \cfrac 23\cdot \cfrac 43 \cdot \cfrac 34\cdot  \cfrac 45 \dots $

Comment: @RainiervanEs - thanks for the latex clarification - I have used it to show how cancellation would cascade through the terms